# How to manage DI with a service that needs a component?

Tags: angular, project

I manage an Angular project using this architecture:

```
  ├── media
  └── src
      ├── app
      │   ├── core <-- services folder inside
      │   ├── data
      │   ├── layout
      │   ├── module
      │   └── shared
      └── styles
```

I got my services inside core folder, and my components divided in modules inside module folder. However, I created a new service, that is opening an emergency modal. It requires a component inside module folder. Therefore, it creates a DI because I inject external dependencies inside the core folder (which needs to remain like this without depending on extra folder).
How can I manage this DI? Do I insert the module inside the core folder?

Here is my service code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmergencyService {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  onOpenModal(): void {
    this.modalService.open(EmergencyComponent);
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Architecture from [link](https://github.com/mathisGarberg/angular-folder-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code of your service?

I use a similar architecture with multiple module and I have a service for my modals too. In my case using:

> `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

on top of my service works fine, but all my shared component are defined in root module, also basic modal opened by modal service

Comment: The service is called from a guard inside core/guards. I am using submodule only